# What is the conda install option to fallback to pip for those packages unavailable to conda directly?

Tags: python, pip, conda

[The documentation for using pip in a conda environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) states:

"install as many requirements as possible with conda, then use pip"

What is the `conda install` option that will do this automatically?

Comment: There is no automatic option. You have to do it manually.